# ItemsPanelTemplate issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to use a `Grid` as `PanelTemplate`. That's not big deal, but i need to have other controls in that `Grid` too. So my ItemsControl looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemscontname" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" Grid.Column="0"
              ItemsPanel="{StaticResource gridKey}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button .../>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style>
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowNumber}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnNumber}" />
            </Style.Setters>
         </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

And my ItemsPanelTemplate:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="gridKey">
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                ....
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                ....
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     </Grid>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

And that's fine, it works. But In this `Grid` I would like to have, let's say a `TextBlock`.

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="gridKey">
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                ....
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                ....
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                   Text="{Binding SomeTextFromVM}"/>
     </Grid>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

When i do this, it spoils everything. How should i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would usually add elements in the `Template` of the ItemsControl, which you would have in addition to the `ItemsPanel` template.

You can't however add those elements to the Grid in the ItemsPanel (which is managed by the ItemsPresenter).

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Grid>
                ...
                <ItemsPresenter/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                           Text="{Binding SomeTextFromVM}"/> 
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                ...
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        ...
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: <ItemsPresenter/>  what is this for?

Comment: It's where your items get added to the template. If you want something in the grid, add it before or after the <ItemsPresenter/>

Comment: updated the question. This way the style is messed up. My goal is to have the buttons on the grid's edges, like a board game.